# MS Access Created default value on form field, not showing

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an `Inventory` table set up like this:

- `ItemCode` is the primary key
- `SalesPrice`

I have a `WSales` table with:

- `ID` as primary key
- `ItemCode` (duplicates allowed)
- `SalesPrice`
- `SalesQty`

On the capture form I want to capture the `SalesQty` and the `SalesPrice` for an `ItemCode`. This `SalesPrice` is usually the same as the `SalesPrice` field in the `Inventory` table but it could vary. So to save capture time I would like the `SalesPrice` from `Inventory` to show on the form as the default value.
I have created a default value for `SalesPrice` on the form as

```
=[Inventory]![SalesPrice]
```

Does not work as the form field remains empty
The two tables are linked by `ItemCode` in a one to many relationship
Any suggestions would be most welcome.
By the way, new to Access so not yet up to speed on VBA or SQL
Using Access in Office365

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are specifying a field where you want to return a single value. How should Access know which member of the SalesPrice field you want to return?

The answer is a query. In Access the command is called DLOOKUP. It would go something like this:

```
=DLookUp("[WholeSalePrice]","[Inventory]","[ItemCode]=" & Forms![WorkShop Sales Capture]![ItemCode])
```

This is like an SQL query that says give me the SalesPrice from the Inventory table where the ItemCode is the same as the ItemCode on Form Capture. You will have to ensure that the form name is correct. I put "Capture" in there because that is what you called the form.

Comment: Thanks for reply but still does not work. Maybe my code is wrong, I have it as:  =DLookUp("[Inventory]![WholeSalePrice]"," [Inventory]","[Inventory]![ItemCode] = " & [Forms![WorkShop Sales Capture]![ItemCode])            When I go back to Form view, the lockup field contains  #Name?          So I must have missed something but cannot see it

Comment: There are many syntax errors in the text you have there in this comment. I updated my answer based on your code. Try it again.

Comment: Also, I never use spaces in names. You might want to remove the spaces from the name of your form...